# Why did not the Demons attack Ellcrys directly?

Tags: shannara, elfstones-of-shannara

In The *Elfstones of Shannara*, the Demons break through the Forbidding, then mass up and attack the Elves as an army, intent on destroying Ellcrys along with the Elves (or preventing her rebirth).

Why did Dagda Mor not destroy Ellcrys in the beginning, as soon as he broke through the Forbidding himself, along with a small team of fellow Demons (when they killed the Chosen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because Ellcrys, while alive and strong, is anathema to the Demons.

<sup>The Elfstones Of Shannara, Chapter 20</sup>

> “The time will come very soon now when the Ellcrys can no longer maintain the wall of the Forbidding with sufficient strength to contain the remainder of the Demons still imprisoned within. When that time comes, the Demons will concentrate their strength at the wall’s weakest point and break free. We cannot wait for that to happen. We must find the place where they will attempt their crossover and do what we can to prevent it. Even if we fail, we can fight a delaying action which will slow them in their march on Arborlon. They will try to march here, for they will seek to destroy the Ellcrys. They must. They cannot tolerate her. Remember that **while she was strong, she was anathema to them**. But as she weakens, she becomes less so. Once they have broken through her wall, they will move quickly to destroy her. We must do what we can to prevent that. We must give Amberle time to reach the Bloodfire and return again. We must keep the Demons from Arborlon until then.